# Highlighting days on DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net, datepicker

I have the standard date time picker on a vb.net project and just wondered if it's possible to have the days highlighted that contain an array of dates from my designated directory.

Basically once my program is opened it reads the contents of the text files in a directory and stores the information in an array. These dates are 'planned jobs' for an employee and the job details are displayed in a listbox once the day is selected. I'm thinking I would like to give an indication on the calendar for any dates that contain jobs and have it highlighted a bit like 'today's date'

Just wondered if anyone has done this AND if they could point me in the right direction of where to research this

Thanks

Comment: sounds interesting, but also outside the scope of the DatePicker (and OT for SO).  You probably want a schedule or calendat control, there are several decent ones out there

Comment: Thanks - I'll have a look at those